# How do I create an object of a class using user input as the object name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have searched for this topic many times now and I still can't find an example that I understand very well. I am fairly new to Python and I am working on a personal project to learn the language and basic GUI.

[The init function of my Profile Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1nXz.png)

My program is very simple, it's just a password manager. I'm trying to store user profiles and their contents in a class with the object name as the profile name of the user. What can I do to dynamically create objects of this class as a new user uses this program and creates a profile?

Comment: Objects don't have names. If you mean you want to dynamically create a variable, the. You*shouldn't do that*. Use a *container*, like a list or a dict

Comment: Please post the code as text not an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good reason why this isn't allowed - by allowing users to name variables in the global scope arbitrarily, you're opening yourself up for overwriting something important. I'd say the best solution would be a `dict`:

```py
p_name = input("Profile name:")
profiles[p_name] = Profile("password")
```